# Navbar collapse in Bootstrap 3 is not working

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some following HTML codes with Twitter bootstrap...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive"/></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-3 pull-right">
                <ul class="social pull-right ul-social-link">
                                <li style="background: none"> <a href="#"> <i class=" fa fa-facebook">   </i> </a> </li>
                                <li style="background: none"> <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-twitter">   </i> </a> </li>
                                <li style="background: none"> <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus">   </i> </a> </li>
                            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 pull-right">
                <div class="col-md-5 pull-right text-right">
                    <p class="contact"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> +912345678910</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 pull-right">
                    <p class="contact"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span> mail@indtechhc.com</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a><li>
                        <li><a href="#">We are</a><li>
                        <li><a href="#">Products</a><li>
                        <li><a href="#">About us</a><li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a><li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

But it is not working when I trigger the collapse button! please advise.

Comment: how do you want the result ?

Comment: It works here: http://www.bootply.com/aK7mfFCv2H Could something else in your code (JS or CSS) be messing with it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm with @neilsimp1.  It also works in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/#&togetherjs=1LatDgaUvM)

Comment: what would be that missing element?

Comment: Did you remember to include bootstrap.js in your `<head>` section?

Comment: @MuneebPullani Wouldn't know without looking. Perhaps just forgetting to include Bootstrap or jQuery? I know one time I had some css that changed the z-index and I had to bump up the z-index on `.navbar-toggle` to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you include jquery.js and that it is before bootstrap.min.js